# Querying EF to get value from Foreign Key with custom entity <T>

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I´m new using EF, and I don´t know how to solve a simple select, I have two entity types like:

```
 IEnumerable<T> Listar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "");
```

and

```
  T Cargar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
            string includeProperties = "");
```

And I have two tables

Estatus Table:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | Nombre   | 
+----+----------+
| 1  | ACTIVE   |
+----+----------+
| 2  | DISABLED |
+----+----------+
```

Tipos Carga Table:

```
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | Nombre | Descripcion  | EstatusID | 
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 1  | store  | description1 | 2         |  
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 2  | oxo    | description2 | 2         | 
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
```

And I´m getting values like:

```
     var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid));
 List<TipoCargaViewModel> tiposcargas = new List<TipoCargaViewModel>();

                    foreach (var item in tc)
                    {
                        var carga = new TipoCargaViewModel()
                        {
                            ID =  item.ID,
                            Nombre = item.Nombre,
                            Descripcion = item.Descripcion,
                            EstatusID = item.EstatusID
                        };
                        tiposcargas.Add(carga);
                    }
```

That I want to do is to get value `Nombre` of Estatus Table, where `EstatusID` of table Carga equals to ID of table Estatus

First I try to get all values of carga table like:

```
 var cargatc = _tipoCargaService.Listar().ToList();
```

then call estatus like:

```
var estatus = _estatusService.Cargar(x => x.Nombre.Where(ID == cargatc.EstatusID));
```

but I can´t equals `Nombre.Where(ID == cargatc.EstatusID)`

I get `Cannot resolve symbol ID` and is marked as red and same for `cargatc.EstatusID`. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the functionality baked into your methods, at least seemingly, via the `includeProperties` param. All your need to do is add your related entity there:

```
var tc = _tipoCargaService.Listar(c => c.EstatusID.Equals(estatusid), includeProperties: "Estatus");
```

Then:

```
var carga = new TipoCargaViewModel()
{
    ID =  item.ID,
    Nombre = item.Estatus.Nombre,
    Descripcion = item.Descripcion,
    EstatusID = item.EstatusID
};
```

This of course necessitates that you have a navigation property on your `TiposCarga` entity class:

```
public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you don't really need a VM for this, you just need to make sure your navigation properties are intact and it will make your life much easier.

1. Verify your navigation properties are setup properly in EF:

   ```
   public class Estatus
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public String Nombre { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<TipoCarga> TipoCargas { get; set; }
   }

   public class TipoCarga
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public String Nombre { get; set; }
       public String Descripcion { get; set; }
       public virtual Estatus Estatus { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Use Include keyword to load your object and linked objects when selecting so that they will be included in the return. If you do not do this, lazy loading will take effect and the linked objects will not be loaded (you will get an error when trying to access the linked objects properties when outside your data context):

   ```
   public List<TipoCarga> GetWhatever(int estatusid)
   {
       using (DB context = new DB())
       {
           return context.TipoCargas.Include("Estatus").Where(a => a.Estatus.ID == estatusid).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```

[image]